# How can I extract all phrases from a sentence?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I want to extract all the possible meaningful phrases from a sentence
For example:
"Food was fantastic in the local restaurant and the restaurant was perfectly romantic."
I want:
Food was fantastic
Food was fantastic in the local restaurant
the restaurant was perfectly romantic
etc

I don't mind if there are some additional phrases that come up as I am planning to use Vader sentiment analysis to remove neutral phrases. Another approach that would work for me is if there is a way to extract phrases around a keyword, then I can use python rake to get the keywords

This is a project to extract all possible positive and negative phrases for UGC reviews that we collect, our initial approach was to use regex patterns to extract phrases and then pass them through Vader to get sentiments but this was omitting a lot of phrases, now we are trying to shortlist sentences with a sentiment and then extracting phrases from  it,

Answer (score 0):

You might do [a constituency parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parse_tree#Constituency-based_parse_trees) of the sentences and gradually remove phrases.

Constituency parsing for 11 languages can be added to spacy with [Berkeley Neural Parser](https://github.com/nikitakit/self-attentive-parser).

Here is a snippet from github:

```py
>>> import spacy
>>> from benepar.spacy_plugin import BeneparComponent
>>> nlp = spacy.load('en')
>>> nlp.add_pipe(BeneparComponent("benepar_en2"))
>>> doc = nlp(u"The time for action is now. It's never too late to do something.")
>>> sent = list(doc.sents)[0]
>>> print(sent._.parse_string)
(S (NP (NP (DT The) (NN time)) (PP (IN for) (NP (NN action)))) (VP (VBZ is) (ADVP (RB now))) (. .))
>>> sent._.labels
('S',)
>>> list(sent._.children)[0]
The time for action
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice Python library called `constituent_treelib` which can, among other tasks, be used to extract all phrases with respect to their categories (e.g. noun or verb phrases).

First, install it via:

```
pip install constituent-treelib
```

Then, perform the following steps to extract the phrases of the mentioned sentence "*Food was fantastic in the local restaurant and the restaurant was perfectly romantic.*":

```
from constituent_treelib import ConstituentTree

# Define the sentence
sentence = 'Food was fantastic in the local restaurant and the restaurant was perfectly romantic.'

# Define the language that should be considered 
language = ConstituentTree.Language.English

# Construct the neccesary NLP pipeline by downloading and installing the required models (benepar and spaCy)
nlp = ConstituentTree.create_pipeline(language, download_models = True)

# Instantiate a ConstituentTree object and pass it both the sentence and the NLP pipeline
tree = ConstituentTree(sentence, nlp)

# Finally, extract all phrases 
tree.extract_all_phrases(avoid_nested_phrases=True)

# Result
# -------------------------------------------------

{'ADJP': ['perfectly romantic'],
 'VP': ['was fantastic in the local restaurant', 'was perfectly romantic'],
 'NP': ['the local restaurant', 'the restaurant'],
 'S': ['Food was fantastic in the local restaurant and the restaurant was perfectly romantic .'],
 'PP': ['in the local restaurant']}
```

That's it. From here on you can do what ever you want with the extracted phrases e.g., classify them with respect to their sentiment. For this I recommend using an off-the-shelf transformer in combination with zero-shot-classification. An example for this can be looked up under:

https://blog.paperspace.com/zero-shot-text-classification-with-hugging-face-on-gradient/